# A list and a form into the same django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a one-page layout for a website, containing a list of latest posts in one section, and a contact form in another section.
That means I need to feed both, the logic for the post list and the contact form, into the same template (home.html)

I made it work as below, but that doesn't feel like the right solution... It's quite messy.

Do you have a better approach?

```
views.py


def post_list(request):

    # Pull relevant posts from the database
    posts = Post.objects.filter(status='Published').order_by('-created')
    return posts


def home_page(request):

    # Contact form logic
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(name, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found')
            messages.success(request, 'Mesage delivered')

    # Call the post_list() function
    posts = post_list(request)

    # Stuff it all into the home page template
    context = {'posts':posts, 'form':form}
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

Comment: This code looks fine to me, what doesn't feel right about it. Just one thing: `post_list` isn't a view and doesn't need a `request` object, why do you put it in a separate function? You could just put the one-liner `posts = Post.objects.filter(...)` directly in your `home_page` view function.

Comment: One other thing: If `form.is_valid()` you're returning the same bound form (adding a success message). Wouldn't it be better to clear the form?

Comment: It seems cleaner to keep the different pieces of logic in separate functions... to keep everything nice and short, and I think it would simplify testing. Thanks for the suggestion with the one liner inside home_page, works perfectly.

Comment: The function `post_list` shouldn't be in views.py because as I said it's not a view. If you really want to keep separation of logic, your post list should actually be on the `Manager` of your model so you would then just add `posts = Post.objects.published()` in your `home_page` view. See [custom managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) for details on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep the whole thing purely Django, then your approach is fine actually. Except the `post_list` function shouldn't be defined in views.py as it's really not a view function.

Better would be to create a `Post` [custom model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) with a custom method `published()` so that in your `home_page` view function you could just do:

```
posts = Post.objects.published()
```

The `published()` methods "knows" how to filter the correct posts and order them appropriately. In the future it could even return different lists depending on whether the user has certain privileges, e.g. return also posts that will be published in the future for staff members.

This logic belongs in the model (or model manager in this case), not in the view.

Another approach, especially when you start dealing with more complex views that require pieces of information from all kinds of different places, is to create an API view for the list of posts that is fetched via javascript with an ajax call. Then your `home_page()` function only needs to return the rendered HTML template with the form and the javascript will fetch the list of posts separately. More difficult because you have to populate the template using javascript. That's where frameworks like React or Angular come in to make that easier.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think about managers. Awesome, I think that's what I'll do. The API approach is interesting too, probably a good way for me to get into js frameworks since I haven't touch that yet. Thank you!